# AngularJS casting boolean as string in directive scope

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am loading a json feed within an AngularJS directive, using the $http method:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/comments/'
}).then(function (res) {
    console.log(1, JSON.stringify(res.data.results[0]));
    scope.items = res.data.results;
    console.log(2, JSON.stringify(scope.items[0]));
});
```

At step one I get:

```
deliverable: true
id: 8100
```

At step two (after the template compiles) I get:

```
$$hashKey: "object:84"
deliverable: "false"
id: 8100
```

Why is AngularJS casting a boolean as a string, and the wrong string value?

[image: Console output showing before and after]

I've tried to replicate in a JSFiddle, but it doesn't give me the same result, it seems to work fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/709uc3x8/2/